# Filter but get object - django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am doing:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(name=givenname).latest('added')
```

But I am getting a Queryset:

```
[<MyModel: object title>]
```

But I need only the object, How can I get only object and not Queryset by using `filter()` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using `filter` use `get` (or in addition)

In your case:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(name=givenname).latest('added')
```

Or:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(name=givenname).get()
```

Comment: @doniyor: looking at the API, `latest()` should already give you a single item. Your results don't make any sense, can you post your model and manager?

Comment: ``latest()`` gives you object only if you dont use ``filter()`` - am i right?

Comment: Not according to the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.latest So I think your manager overrides the `latest()` method.

Comment: `.get()` gives you a single object and assumes your query just gives a single result. `.latest()` gives you a single object which is the newest one according to the field you're sorting by.

Comment: what if i first filter and from queryset in the second step get the object?! :)

Comment: Well, you can always do `[0]` of course, but I'm still not sure why you are getting a queryset (or list) of objects. Can you add the definitions?

Comment: You can also try out the .last() call, gives you the last object added to your model. Also works with .first()